# Alamofire upload "name" parameter

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

In the Alamofire `upload` code there is a `name` and `fileName` field.

```
Alamofire.upload(
                    .POST,
                    "http://192.168.1.241:8080/file/user",
                    multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
                        multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: imageData, name: "file", fileName: "file", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
                    },
                    encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
                        switch encodingResult {
                        case .Success(let upload, _, _):
                            upload.progress { bytesWritten, totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite in
                                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                                    let percent = (Float(totalBytesWritten) / Float(totalBytesExpectedToWrite))
                                    //progress(percent: percent)
                                    print(percent)
                                }
                            }
                            upload.responseJSON { response in
                                debugPrint(response)
                            }
                        case .Failure(let encodingError):
                            debugPrint(encodingError)
                        }
                    }
                    )
```

In my Spring server I looking for `@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file` and I could not get it to work because I was setting `name` to `file`. But apparently I needed to set the `fileName` to `"file"`.

What exactly is the purpose of `name` if it doesn't seem to be used for request parameter mapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For "**file**" it means the full `NSURL` property of your file (example: www.mysite.com/myvideo.mp4), for "**filename**" just only the `lastPathComponent` in `String` format (example: video.mp4)

Comment: but why does it need a `NSURL` property of the file when you are already passing the `NSData` of the file?

Comment: Because the NSURL property can be composed by some parameters  when the NSData contain just only the file data, so the sources distinguish well the request by the econding of the MultipartFormData. Alamofire is a complex framework based on NSMutableURLRequest.